# Dynamics charts using chartist and angular with ng-repeate

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, chartist.js, angular-chartist.js

I now and I can show a chart with dynamic data but a fixed number of chart. When I want to show a dynamic number of charts, something happens with ng-repeate. I said something happens, because if in **mycharts[0].container.outerHTML** I had the html that I need to show the graph (generated by the library), and if I copy and paste in a fixed place in my html, it will show the graph. My **ng-repeate** code looks as follow:

```html
<div class="row" ng-controller="nodesDataTablesCtrl as nodeCtrl" >
  <div  ng-repeat="(index, node) in nodeCtrl.nodes"  on-finish-render>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="{{ node.name }}_MEMORY" class="ct-chart snp_dynamic_chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I'm not sure if is a bug of ng-repeate or Chartist.

**In my ng-repeate** I use **nodeCtrl.nodes**, which **is an array that I receive from an http.get**, my solution was create an **range** function, wich is, a function that **receive a Number and return a list from 0 to n-1.** Instead of passing the nodeCtrl.nodes which is updated everytime I make a request, I update a variable **numberOfNodes** with the range function, I mean, my new ng-repeat will be as follow:

```
<div  ng-repeat="(index, node) in nodeCtrl.numberOfNodes"  on-finish-render>
```

and in the success function of my request I do:

```
numberOfNodes = range(nodeCtrl.nodes.length)
```

which from my point of view make that ng-repeate don't update in some way internally.

Is important to se that programatically it shouldn't be differen but ...

Comment: Something similar happens after with an uiprogressBar and the max parameter for somereason the value parameter work great with reference to a field in nodes object property, but in max it didn't, I make a variable in my controller and it work